# Background color not appearing in free-jqGrid that is present in jqGrid 4.6.0

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am migrating existing jqGrid (4.6.0) to free-jqGrid (4.13.6 or later).  Following two fiddles has same JavaScript and HTML – but one with 4.6.0 jqGrid and the other with free-jqGrid (4.13.6 for now)

1. **jqGrid (4.6.0)** Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vth5wn64/2/
2. **free-jqGrid (4.13.6)** Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vth5wn64/3/

The free-jqGrid does not have the required background color on the caption area. What is missing here? How to fix this?

[image]

[image]

**JavaScript**

```
function getCurrentPractice ()
{
    return "Test";
}

function getGridCaption() {
    return "<div style='font-size:15px; font-weight:bold; display:inline; padding-left:10px;'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-check' style='margin-right:3px;font-size:14px;'></span>" + getCurrentPractice() + " " + "</div>" +
    "<div style='float:right; padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:10px; display:inline;>" +
   "<div style='float:right;width:550px;  padding-bottom:20px;'>" +
        "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='filter' placeholder='Search'  style='width:250px; height:30px; float:right; ' />" +
    " </div>" +
    "</div>";
}

$(function () {

    ////Grid
    var myData = [
                       { "Practice": "Test1", "ProviderID": 1, "IsPartner": true, "IsActive": true },
                       { "Practice": "Test2", "ProviderID": 2, "IsPartner": true, "IsActive": true }
    ]

    var currentPractice = "P";
    var grid = $("#list2");
    grid.jqGrid({
        datatype: 'local',
        data: myData,
        additionalProperties: ["IsActive", "IsPartner"],
        //additionalProperties is needed since the name is different
        postData:
        {
            practiceName: function () { return currentPractice }
        },

        colNames: [
                    'Practice',
                    'ProviderID'
        ],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Practice', width: 220 },
            { name: 'ProviderID', width: 320 }
        ],
        ignoreCase: true,
        loadonce: true,
        rowNum: 25,
        rowList: [15, 25, 35, 50],
        pager: '#pager2',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortable: true,
        caption: getGridCaption(),
         beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
            //Avoid selection of row
            return false;
        },
        loadComplete: function () {

        }


    });
    grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager2', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });

    //Filter Toolbar
    //grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" });
    $("#advancedSearch").click(function () {
        grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" });
    });


    //Top Search
    $("#filter").on('keyup', function () {
        var searchFiler = $("#filter").val(), f;

        //alert(searchFiler);

        if (searchFiler.length === 0) {
            grid[0].p.search = false;
            $.extend(grid[0].p.postData, { filters: "" });
        }
        f = { groupOp: "OR", rules: [] };
        f.rules.push({ field: "Practice", op: "cn", data: searchFiler });
        grid[0].p.search = true;
        $.extend(grid[0].p.postData, { filters: JSON.stringify(f) });
        grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 1, current: true }]);
    });


});
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="float:left;">
    <div id="divGrid" style="width: 680px; min-height: 50px; float: left;">
        <table id="list2"></table>
        <div id="pager2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, both demos uses classes `glyphicon`, `glyphicon-check` and `form-control`. Thus I suppose that you use Bootstrap CSS additionally to jQuery UI CSS.

I'm not sure, which exact layout you want to have, but one thing is definitively a problem. You use inner divs with `float:right` inside of the capture (title) div. It's well known that the classic alignment of blocks using `float` property has the problem. One solves it typically by including some helper element (for example one more div) which has `clear: both;`. jQuery UI CSS contains `ui-helper-clearfix` class, which simplifies applying float wrapping properties to parent elements.

In short, you need just add additional

```html
<div class='ui-helper-clearfix'></div>
```

at the end on the content, which you insert in the caption of jqGrid. See https://jsfiddle.net/vth5wn64/5/